# C# UTC DateTime query in WCF/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc

This is a very simple, (hopefully) question. I am new to working with DateTime conversion in .NET.

I have a WCF service which has a DateTime property - call it BookingDate.

Someone passes that to my WCF service in the format:

```
<a:BookingDate>2012-03-26T17:03:00-04:00</a:BookingDate>
```

The server that it is sitting on is set to a timezone of UTC (Lisbon, London, Dublin).

When I store the corresponding value in the database, it sets the value to be:

```
2012-03-26 22:03
```

I assumed, I think incorrectly that the .NET framework (as part of the WCF serialize/deserialize process) would pop this into a .Net Datetime of UTC for me (as there is the minus offset of 4 hours as above)

I was expecting: `2012-03-26 21:03`

My question is thus: would I need to call:

```
var date = fromClientWCFService.BookingDate.ToUniversalTime();
```

in order to get the 21:03 time that I am expecting?

If not, is there a WCF setting to tell my service to convert DateTimes to UTC, rather than the server timezone?

Thanks in advance

Mark

**EDIT:**

From 1 answer, I can see that DateTimeOffset can be used. Following on from this, would the following work: `var offset = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2012-03-26T17:03:00-0400");` to return the result: `2012-03-26 21:03`

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259005/handling-wcf-deserialization-of-datetime-objects

Comment: Is this indeed a dupe?  If it is, then we should shut it down as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the [`DateTime` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), you should use the [`DateTimeOffset` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx).

The `DateTimeOffset` structure captures the offset from a specified time (it's not UTC by default, it's defined by the scope of *your* application, but the most common offset would be from UTC) *along* with the date/time information, and that information will flow through WCF calls (as well as to a database, assuming it supports the type.  SQL Server in this case has the [`datetimeoffset` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) from 2008 on).

As a matter of fact, [using `DateTimeOffset` is the preferred methods of dealing with date/time data in almost *all* situations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx).  Note from the previous link:

> These uses for DateTimeOffset values are much more common than those
>   for DateTime values. As a result, DateTimeOffset should be considered
>   the default date and time type for application development.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (especially so quickly). Can you confirm my findings above. As in - I want to understand if I was on the right lines, had I wanted to implement it that way?

Comment: Also, unfortunately I can only store datetime - sql server 2005 shop... :(

Comment: @harrisonmeister See the link of the dupe that I posted on the question.

Comment: Hi @casperOne, Thanks - it looks like I was on the right tracks. Glad I'm not going totally bonkers!

Answer (score 0):

If your server's timezone is on Lisbon/London/Dublin time, it is not UTC. You will either want to change the time zone of your server, or express the date/time value in UTC form when you update it in your database.

Comment: Does this mean that the WCF Service will convert that date time to Local time (e.g. Lisbon/London/Ireland) ?

Comment: There's really no "conversion" going on. Your DateTime has a specific value, and that is based on the data it receives. Unfortunately, it also likes to assume that the date is in local time if there is none specified. So, since the datetime out of your DB has no locale information attached to it, .NET decides that it is local, not universal, time. Express your value as UTC (using .ToUniversalTime) going into the DB, and construct it with a DateTimeKind of UTC coming out. That should give you the consistency you seek.