# WCF Method throwing SerializationException

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, serialization

So I'm self hosting a WCF service. When I call my GetProject() method via the client I get a Unhandled CommuncationException with an InnerException of

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive."

And the InnerException of that:

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Now I know this is just a generic message that doesn't tell me much. So I configured a Service Trace and this is what I got:

> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.FormatException' with data contract name 'FormatException:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

So I took this message and modified my code and I believe now that I am doing this correctly. I have followed several tutorials, but I still keep getting this exception in the Service Trace.

In my `ServiceContract` I have the following:

```
[OperationContract]
Project GetProject(int id);
```

**Edit Removed `KnownTypeAttribute` use. Commented out here to reflect the changes.**

Here is my implementation of the Project class and the classes that it utilizes:

```
    [DataContract]
    //[KnownType(typeof(Contact))]
    //[KnownType(typeof(ProjectDetails))]
    //[KnownType(typeof(CommercialEntity))]
    public class Project
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ProjectDetails details = new ProjectDetails();
        [DataMember]
        public List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        [DataMember]
        public List<CommercialEntity> POs = new List<CommercialEntity>();
        [DataMember]
        public List<CommercialEntity> invoices = new List<CommercialEntity>();
        [DataMember]
        public List<CommercialEntity> quotes = new List<CommercialEntity>();
        [DataMember]
        public List<CommercialEntity> CRs = new List<CommercialEntity>();
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ProjectDetails 
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int projectId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int calYearId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string projectState { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string reportTitle { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int plantId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string holdNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string holdDescription { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string remarks { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string adminComments {get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int customerId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string folderNumber { get;  set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int invoicedInFull { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int approved { get; set; }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CommercialEntity
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string number { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string comments { get; set; }

        public CommercialEntity(string setNumber, DateTime setDate, string setComments)
        {
            number = setNumber;
            date = setDate;
            comments = setComments;
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Contact
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int alert { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int projectLead { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int mainContact { get; set; }

        public Contact(string first, string last, string email, string phone, int alrt, int projLead, int mainCntct)
        {
            firstName = first;
            lastName = last;
            emailAddress = email;
            phoneNumber = phone;
            alert = alrt;
            projectLead = projLead;
            mainContact = mainCntct;
        }

        public Contact() { }
    }
```

Where is the hole in my understanding?

Here is what I see when I run the client:

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ******* *Exception Text* *********
>
> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while
>   receiving the HTTP response to
>   myInternalIP:myPort/ProjectService/ProjectService. This could be
>   due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This
>   could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs
>   for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)
>
> at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>
> at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>
> at IProjectService.GetQuerytoList(Int32 id)
>
> at ProjectServiceClient.GetQuerytoList(Int32 id) in
>   C:\Users\drwill\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ProjectBaseWCF\ProjectBase\generatedProxy.cs:line 1065
>   at ProjectWCFClient.MainForm.openToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\drwill\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ProjectBaseWCF\ProjectBase\PBMain.cs:line 961
>
> at ProjectWCFClient.MainForm.ProjectListBox_DoubleClick(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\Users\drwill\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\ProjectBaseWCF\ProjectBase\PBMain.cs:line 55
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Here is my Client config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IProjectService" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000000" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.0.99:9000/ProjectService/ProjectService"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IProjectService"
                contract="IProjectService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IProjectService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Here is my service config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ProjectBaseWCFServiceLib.Service1Behavior" name="ProjectBaseWCFServiceLib.ProjectService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ProjectBaseWCFServiceLib.IProjectService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ProjectBaseWCFServiceLib/Service1/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ProjectBaseWCFServiceLib.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

In addition, I programatically configure my Console App Host with:

```
     BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
     binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
     binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
     binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
     binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
     binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 500000000;
     binding.MaxBufferSize = 500000000;
     binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 500000000;

     selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IProjectService), binding, "ProjectService");
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167932/c-sharp-wcf-when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-the-knowntype-attribute

Comment: Side note: those new() statements and constructors may not be working the way you're expecting.

Comment: Is Proxy client and server running on same machine?

Comment: No, the server is running on a different machine than the client.

Comment: Same issue with KnownType removed?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I'll post the StackTrace.

Comment: Posted the StackTrace.

Comment: Yeah, you have something else going on here now. Can you post your config for this service?

Comment: Yes, I will. Just one moment. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I think you stopped/started the service but not the client (wsHttpBinding?) - please restart both then repro the problem.

Comment: Restarted. Still getting the same thing.

Comment: @DaveZiegler: I posted the configs.

Comment: @DerekW: we can only help if you can repro the original SerializationException. It looks like now you've got some different issue. Both your endpoints in client have same address - which one you are using? Remove the one which you dont want.

Comment: @Yk1: I have my service configured to the print the service log. That is where the SerializationException is being revealed.

Comment: The StackTrace I provided is what is seen on the client.

Comment: Alright. Is there a stack trace on server? Or just to zero down can you change the DateTime to string and re-create proxy and try to repro?

Comment: looks like binding config is your issue - updated my answer

Comment: What was the conclusion here, was it web.config issues in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. So this is a bit late, but here is what it was:

The `System.FormatException` that was being thrown was due to the occurrence of an `int.Parse("0")` inside the `GetProject(int id)` method when I was calling it.

So I altered the method to handle the `"0"` case by calling the much more robust `Convert.ToInt32("0")`.

I think the lesson learned here is that you should first make sure that the method you are executing works. Then and only then should you start asking if the `DataContractSerializer` is not adequate to serialize your types.

Comment: I was trying to figure out the problem for hours... I've found out that in my case the issue was an enum (parameter) was not correctly converted to a string.You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need KnownType - It could be possible parsing error with DateTime. Check culture on client and server machines.

EDIT: From further information provided, it looks like your proxy is incorrectly configured - compared to the binding configurations on the server. Re-create the proxy using Add Service Reference or SvcUtil.exe

Comment: I agree with the first part! I'm not so sure about the DateTime bit, there can be KnownType issues with DateTimeOffset, though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Comment: @dave - DateTimeOffset is not used in the code - perhaps that is what should be used. Or send date as UTC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878560/c-sharp-utc-datetime-query-in-wcf-net

Comment: Culture on both machines is `en-US`.

Comment: I updated my code. The more I read about the `KnownTypeAttribute` the more it became apparent that I was using it wrong.

Comment: @YK1: I understand, I was just saying I didn't see any issues with DateTime.

Comment: @DerekW: is time zone also same?

Comment: @DerekW: culture en-US is OK.. where did you check? You have to go to regional and language settings and check date format. Just want to confirm its same.

Comment: Yes, I checked Region and Language in Control Panel on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a parameterless constructor for `CommercialEntity`

Comment: Good observation - but unfortunately WCF DataContractSerializer does not use constructors -  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx#S5

Comment: I added it, but as YK1 suspected, no dice.