# How can I convert a WCF style formatted date string i.e. "/Date(1342210377000)/" to c# DateTime?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, datetime, datacontractserializer

An ajax request sends a date value in WCF format? It's a javascript date object converted to a string WCF can deserialize using the DataContractSerializer.

```
"/Date(1342210377000)/"
```

the client used to send this data to a WCF service, but now this is sent to an asp.net mvc controller. Does anyone know how I can deserialize that string into a c# DateTime without doing a bun of string.replace operations? Is there an existing .NET serializer I can leverage? I looked at using the DataContractSerializer but it's readobject method takes a stream or xmlreader. I could not figure out how convert a modelbindercontext.valueprovider value to a stream object the serializer could use. If anyone knows how I can correctly convert that string I would love to learn how.  Thanks for any tips, tricks, code, links, etc...

Comment: Not a C# solution, but a general idea: Use a regexp like `\d{1,}` to get the numeric value, divide by `1000` to get UNIX timestamp and use http://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/759049 to get the desired `DateTime`.

Comment: Didn't this post help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259005/handling-wcf-deserialization-of-datetime-objects

Comment: I don't think that this is the only part you have to deserialize. If you show the whole string you get from client you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to convert that into a `DateTime` value:

```
var str = "\"/Date(1342210377000)/\"";
var dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DateTime));
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
var dt = dcjs.ReadObject(ms);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Comment: Awesome Carlos, the memorystream piece was exactly what I was looking for. This worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
DateTime.ToUniversalTime()
```

Say for example, this gives you the output format as "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" than take that and let your C# code do the formatting part however you want.

Comment: -1 OP has a string ( `"/Date(1342210377000)/"` ) not a DateTime and asks how to convert it to DateTime