# DataMember DateTime with Null Values in WCF throwing Error Angular $http

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf, datetime

I have a DataContract Object with DataMember DateTime

```
  [DataMember]
  public DateTime ModDateApproval { get; set; }
```

This field has null values which converted to DateTime MinValue in C#.

My WCF Service is working in SoapUI but doesn't work in Angular $http. I am consuming the service directly in angular and the service is working when I remove the field as DataMember.

[image]

Comment: It's highly likely that it's a serialization issue. What is the date value you're sending?

Comment: Null Date values are automatically converted to DateTime.MinValue in c# which is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM and is now resolved by making in DateTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime();. I am intrigued why it needs to be converted to .ToUniversalTime();

Comment: Why not make the property nullable? `public DateTime? ModDateApproval`. This should more accurately reflect your intent. Setting MinValue to universal time seems like a kludgy solution.

Comment: Okay. I guess that is a more straightforward approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My issue is related to this question. Perhaps DateTime only needs to be manipulated in web service like this:

```
 if(x.MyDate == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                x.MyDate = DateTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime();
            }
```

[Handling WCF Deserialization of DateTime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259005/handling-wcf-deserialization-of-datetime-objects?rq=1)